# Interactive Stack Exchange Network User Maps

Tags: discussion

Just a heads up discussion that I thought may be worth putting on this meta as well.

A [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) user (and other SE sites) has come up with [a neat webapp](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/733/101) to see all the users for any particular SE site on a map.

We were quite impressed to see all the users we have, although only one user in any of the 'stans - in Kazakhstan (Almaty).

Anyway, suggestions for additions welcomed [on the other meta](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/733/101).

Comment: Discussions about apps should go to the apps [stackapps](http://stackapps.com/questions/3367/stackmaps-interactive-maps-of-stackexchange-communities) page, not on travel's meta. (And I'm not sure how on-topic this post is here)

Comment: is there a way for me to migrate it?

Comment: Flag it and request a migration with a custom message...

Comment: @MarkMayo: there's no need to migrate anything, that app is already listed on stackapps.

Comment: Actually I find it quite interesting to know where my top users are located (time-zone wise) and think if it was buried on Stack Apps, not a whole lot of people would see it. So I don't mind seeing this question here